# Is it possible to detect 32 bit vs 64 bit in a bash script?

Tags: bash

I am writing a bash script to deal with some installations in an automated way... I have the possibility of getting one such program in 32 or 64 bit binary... is it possible to detect the machine architecture from bash so I can select the correct binary?

This will be for Ubuntu machines.

Comment: Detect what? CPU? OS? Userland availability of a cpu architecture? `/proc/cpuinfo` returning 64-bit when the OS is 32-bit is not very helpful in most cases.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Does

```
uname -a
```

give you anything you can use?  I don't have a 64-bit machine to test on.

---

**Note from Mike Stone:** This works, though specifically

```
uname -m
```

Will give "x86_64" for 64 bit, and something else for other 32 bit types (in my 32 bit VM, it's "i686").

Answer (score 84):

```
MACHINE_TYPE=`uname -m`
if [ ${MACHINE_TYPE} == 'x86_64' ]; then
  # 64-bit stuff here
else
  # 32-bit stuff here
fi
```

Comment: instead of `${MACHINE_TYPE}` you could just write `$(uname -m)`, and skip the declaration of another variable.

Comment: Unless you have to use it more then once in your script ...

Comment: On 32 bits machines, this method is not recommended as the answer will be i386, i686, etc... I would advice to favor the `getconf LONG_BIT` method.

Comment: @Speredenn the above doesn't check for the 32-bit name, e.g. i386, i686, etc, but for the 64-bit name.  Your contention is moot unless there are also synonyms for x86_64 that it could return (e.g. amd64, but can it?)

Comment: FYI that does not always seems to match i.e. I see a system where LONG_BIT reports 32, but uname -m reports aarch64

Answer (score 55):

`getconf LONG_BIT` seems to do the trick as well, which makes it even easier to check this since this returns simply the integer instead of some complicated expression.

```
if [ `getconf LONG_BIT` = "64" ]
then
    echo "I'm 64-bit"
else
    echo "I'm 32-bit"
fi
```

Comment: It's good, but does not work on msys.

Comment: On the other hand it works in WSL!

Comment: I think, this should be used carefully on other architectures. I think this will return 64 on aarch64 too.

Answer (score 15):

Be careful, in a `chroot`ed 32-bit env, the uname is still answering like the 64-bit host system.

`getconf LONG_BIT` works fine.

`file /bin/cp` or any well-known executable or library should do the trick if you don't have getconf (but you can store programs you can't use, and maybe there are not at this place).

Answer (score 10):

You can use , the follow script (i extract this from officially script of "ioquake3") : for example

```
archs=`uname -m`
case "$archs" in
    i?86) archs=i386 ;;
    x86_64) archs="x86_64 i386" ;;
    ppc64) archs="ppc64 ppc" ;;
esac

for arch in $archs; do
    test -x ./ioquake3.$arch || continue
    exec ./ioquake3.$arch "$@"
done
```

==================================================================================

I'm making a script to detect the "Architecture", this is my simple code (I am using it with wine , for my Windows Games , under Linux , by each game , i use diferrent version of WineHQ, downloaded from "PlayOnLinux" site.

```
# First Obtain "kernel" name
KERNEL=$(uname -s)

if      [ $KERNEL = "Darwin" ]; then
        KERNEL=mac
elif        [ $Nucleo = "Linux" ]; then
        KERNEL=linux
elif        [ $Nucleo = "FreeBSD" ]; then
        KERNEL=linux
else
        echo "Unsupported OS"
fi

# Second get the right Arquitecture
ARCH=$(uname -m)

if         [ $ARCH = "i386" ]; then
            PATH="$PWD/wine/$KERNEL/x86/bin:$PATH"
            export WINESERVER="$PWD/wine/$KERNEL/x86/bin/wineserver"
            export WINELOADER="$PWD/wine/$KERNEL/x86/bin/wine"
            export WINEPREFIX="$PWD/wine/data"
            export WINEDEBUG=-all:$WINEDEBUG
            ARCH="32 Bits"
    elif    [ $ARCH = "i486" ]; then
            PATH="$PWD/wine/$KERNEL/x86/bin:$PATH"
            export WINESERVER="$PWD/wine/$KERNEL/x86/bin/wineserver"
            export WINELOADER="$PWD/wine/$KERNEL/x86/bin/wine"
            export WINEPREFIX="$PWD/wine/data"
            export WINEDEBUG=-all:$WINEDEBUG
            ARCH="32 Bits"
    elif    [ $ARCH = "i586" ]; then
            PATH="$PWD/wine/$KERNEL/x86/bin:$PATH"
            export WINESERVER="$PWD/wine/$KERNEL/x86/bin/wineserver"
            export WINELOADER="$PWD/wine/$Nucleo/x86/bin/wine"
            export WINEPREFIX="$PWD/wine/data"
            export WINEDEBUG=-all:$WINEDEBUG
            ARCH="32 Bits"
    elif    [ $ARCH = "i686" ]; then
            PATH="$PWD/wine/$KERNEL/x86/bin:$PATH"
            export WINESERVER="$PWD/wine/$KERNEL/x86/bin/wineserver"
            export WINELOADER="$PWD/wine/$KERNEL/x86/bin/wine"
            export WINEPREFIX="$PWD/wine/data"
            export WINEDEBUG=-all:$WINEDEBUG
            ARCH="32 Bits"
         elif [ $ARCH = "x86_64" ]; then
            export WINESERVER="$PWD/wine/$KERNEL/x86_64/bin/wineserver"
            export WINELOADER="$PWD/wine/$KERNEL/x86_64/bin/wine"
            export WINEPREFIX="$PWD/wine/data"
            export WINEDEBUG=-all:$WINEDEBUG
            ARCH="64 Bits"
    else
        echo "Unsoportted Architecture"
fi
```

==================================================================================

**Now i use this in my bash scripts , because works better in any distro .**

```
# Get the Kernel Name
Kernel=$(uname -s)
case "$Kernel" in
    Linux)  Kernel="linux"              ;;
    Darwin) Kernel="mac"                ;;
    FreeBSD)    Kernel="freebsd"            ;;
* ) echo "Your Operating System -> ITS NOT SUPPORTED"   ;;
esac

echo
echo "Operating System Kernel : $Kernel"
echo
# Get the machine Architecture
Architecture=$(uname -m)
case "$Architecture" in
    x86)    Architecture="x86"                  ;;
    ia64)   Architecture="ia64"                 ;;
    i?86)   Architecture="x86"                  ;;
    amd64)  Architecture="amd64"                    ;;
    x86_64) Architecture="x86_64"                   ;;
    sparc64)    Architecture="sparc64"                  ;;
* ) echo    "Your Architecture '$Architecture' -> ITS NOT SUPPORTED."   ;;
esac

echo
echo "Operating System Architecture : $Architecture"
echo
```

Comment: You should really learn to use Bash's `case` statement, or basic regex/globbing wildcards,  to collapse all four 32-bit handling blocks into a single one, since they are  identical. *(Hint: `i[3456]86` is your friend)*

Comment: @MestreLion : Thank you , now i use the method , i describe in the final , because , in some posix system , with "if" , are not working fine . and with use of "case / esac" works when i wish :D .

Answer (score 7):

```
slot8(msd):/opt # uname -a
Linux slot8a 2.6.21_mvlcge500-electra #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jun 18 16:29:33 \
EDT 2008 ppc64 GNU/Linux
```

Remember, there are other CPU architectures than Intel/AMD...

Comment: not for my company, so I don't have to worry ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like this:

```
if $(uname -a | grep 'x86_64'); then
  echo "I'm 64-bit"
else
  echo "I'm 32-bit"
fi
```

Comment: a bit silly to use `uname -a` and then `grep` it instead of directly using `uname -m`

Answer (score -3):

Yes, **uname -a** should do the trick.  see: http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/win/64bit.html.