# If statement to determine whether a kernel is 32 or 64

Tags: linux, shell, if-statement

I'm trying to know whether a kernel is 64 or 32 in `#!/bin/sh`.

I build this code!

```
krnl=$(uname -i)

# Check whether 64 or 32 bit kernel and download the correct version;
if [ $krnl='i386' ] ; then # 32
  # Do 32-bits stuff
else
  # Do 64-bits stuff
fi
```

But it seems to return always true. What I'm doing wrong, Why this is happening and how I can fix this? What I googled always show me in bash or doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$ uname -i` gives `GenuineIntel` for me.

Comment: @MichałGórny Are you ubuntu user?

Comment: @ant There are some difference. But if you think so I can delete.

Comment: it's not up to me alone to decide Sir, this is my opinion. Please do not delete based on my opinion

Comment: @ant even with that answer I could not make the if statement work. I could detect the kernel version, but I wont be able to distinguish.

Comment: have you tried other options from the answer I marked as duplicate? i.e. `getconf LONG_BIT` should return `64` or `32`. Also have you used `==` instead of `=` in your if statement ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7308155/169277 what does `uname -a` print ?

Comment: @waldyr.ar: No, Gentoo. And vanilla kernel.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate because /bin/sh might not be bash, but the same answer does apply in practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spaces are needed around '=' sign to properly test $krnl value:

```
krnl=$(uname -i)

# Check whether 64 or 32 bit kernel and download the correct version;
if [ $krnl = 'i386' ] ; then # 32
  # Do 32-bits stuff
else
  # Do 64-bits stuff
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Whitesapce is significant in bash. You need spaces around the '=' character, like so:

```
if [ $krnl = 'i386' ] ; then # 32
```

Otherwise, you've defined a long string "x86_64=i386" or "i386=i386", and the non-empty string returns true.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put spaces around the equals sign in the `[` command. Otherwise, it gets a single argument and returns true if that argument is not an empty string, which it will never be.

Also, `uname -m` might be better. I get "unknown" from `uname -i` on an amd64 machine.

Answer (score 0):

On my machine, `uname -p` returns `i686` whereas `uname -i` returns `i386`.

Answer (score 0):

In my console `uname -m`, `uname -i` and `uname -p` return `x86_64` so :

```
krnl=`uname -i`

if [ $krnl="x86_64" ] ; then # 64
  echo "64"
else
  echo "32"
fi
```

<strike>should work</strike>
works on my machine.

**Update :**

```
krnl=`uname -i`
if [ "$krnl" == "x86_64" ]; then
        echo "64"
else
        echo "32"
fi
```

When I change to :

```
if [ "$krnl" != "x86_64" ]; then
```

echoes 32

Comment: You haven't fixed the spacing problem, all you did is reverse it so it always takes the 64 branch instead of always taking the 32 branch. It's still wrong.

Comment: you were right but for different reasons (I didn't just swap). take a look at the edited question

Comment: this is the correct answer I see no reason for down-vote http://stackoverflow.com/a/106416/169277

Comment: The updated version is not as bad. The first one is just wrong. Using `==` in a `[` command is a bashism though.

Comment: true story, `= ''` works as well